# Query from kibana in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, elasticsearch, kibana

I am starting a little script in Python to create a little GET on a query I made in Kibana.
Currently, in Kibana I receive a list of IP with the counts:
[image]

I would like to receive this information in Python and I already try with search but I am not sure to understand.

Here is the query in Kibana:

```
    GET /_search
{
  "size": 0,
  "query": {
      "range": {
        "@timestamp": {
          "gte": 1552922613804,
          "lte": 1552923513804,
          "format": "epoch_millis"
        }
      }
    },
  "aggs": {
    "2": {
      "significant_terms": {
        "field": "origin.keyword",
        "size": 300
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Is it possible to create the same query in python?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Ps: I had put, hello all in my post but is not present xD.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes,just convert your query so python can understand.
If you have authentication setup for elastic you will need to pass your authentication aswell. (username,password) as tuple. Add this to the requests as (auth=(username,password))

```
import json
import requests

HEADERS = {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
}

uri = "[insert your endpoint]"+"/_search"

query = json.dumps({
  "size": 0,
  "query": {
      "range": {
        "@timestamp": {
          "gte": 1552922613804,
          "lte": 1552923513804,
          "format": "epoch_millis"
        }
      }
    },
  "aggs": {
    "2": {
      "significant_terms": {
        "field": "origin.keyword",
        "size": 300
      }
    }
  }
})

r = requests.get(uri,headers=HEADERS, data=query).json()
print(r)
```

Comment: Thanks for your support! So for my case I need to complete the uri = "localhost:9200/myindex"+"/_search" that's correct?

Comment: yes that is correct! Check if it works and let me know ;)
I think "localhost:9200/_search" might already be enough actually aswell, but give both a try. ;)

Comment: I have an error:
    raise InvalidSchema("No connection adapters were found for '%s'" % url)
requests.exceptions.InvalidSchema: No connection adapters were found for 'localhost:9200/checkpoint1/_search'

Comment: 1. You have requests installed?
2. Elastic running?
3. Do you need authentication on elastic or not?

Comment: 1: Yes 2: Yes 3: No :)

Comment: ok, check my other comment. try to specify a protocol. ie http ;)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/191317/discussion-between-nemomemeliorest-and-digitag).

Answer (score 2):

Here's how you can query ES and convert the results to CSV:

```
from elasticsearch import Elasticsearch, helpers
import csv
es = Elasticsearch([“Server”])
query={"query": {"query_string" : {"query" : “(something: True)“}}}
index=[“Index”]
l=[]
with open('my.csv','w') as out:
    csv_out=csv.writer(out)
    csv_out.writerow([‘my’, ‘header’])
    for i in index:
        res=es.search(index=i,doc_type="core-config",body=query,_source_include=[“my”, “header”],size="10000")
        for indexes in res['hits']['hits']:
            l.append((indexes['_source’][‘my’],indexes['_source’][‘header’]))
        set_keyid=list(set(l))
        for lis in set_keyid:
            csv_out.writerow(lis)
```